# Why does my recyclerview item shifts a inch upwards first time?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a button in fragment through which I am opening a activity which has recyclerview.
Whenever I open my activity which contains recyclerview.
Recyclerview item automatically shifts a inch upwards which I don not want to happen in my activity.
I dont know why its happening.
Can any one please help me out?

Comment: Could you attach screenshot how upwards its happening?

Comment: What do you mean by shift ? add screen shot and more explanation ! And add the layout xml too

Comment: @Jai I will post it soon after few hours.

Answer (score 0):

while your question lacks the code or any other reference, i suggest you to try forcing your recycle view to scroll up somewhere after init with:  `<your_layoutManager>.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);`
this is just a temporary fix until you`ll get on top of that

Comment: where\when did you do it?